# How to make the hair have more curl?

Tags: particles, bezier-curves, hair

[image]

I'd like to add more curl to my hair and above is my current one. It has approximately 4 curves currently but I'd like to increase the amount by 9 or 8. But the 'frequency' bar's maximum value is 10 which looks like above. I'd like to increase the value or do other things to increase the amount of curls. Is there a way?

Comment: You may want to try increasing the quality of the hair, as that will provide a better simulation.

Comment: That is what all I've got thought ;c I increased the number of keys and steps to maximum.